# Trying to configure build agent to work with a proxy server

Tags: tfs, proxy, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying to make my build agent work with an already configured proxy server.
The proxy server address is : http://MY_SERVER_DNS:8081

On my build machine inside the agent directory I created a .proxy file which contains the above proxy address and created the relevant environment variables (VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME, VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD).

After a restart to the build agent service the indicator in VSTS goes red (instead of green).
A partial (most relevant I guess) agent log is attached:

```
{ Request = Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://siemplify.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  User-Agent: VSServices/15.255.65000.0
  User-Agent: (NetStandard; Microsoft Windows 6.3.9600)
  User-Agent: VstsAgentCore-win7-x64/2.120.2
  User-Agent: (Microsoft Windows 6.3.9600)
  X-VSS-E2EID: 5aadb1b3-6269-4998-b258-4a5fcc1b9345
  Accept-Language: en-US
  X-TFS-FedAuthRedirect: Suppress
  X-TFS-Session: 13f3aaa0-7f5c-40e1-8af0-0b5feb53d4bc
  Expect: 100-continue
}, LoggingRequestId = ab31853f-a392-486f-b288-f9ca4bdee28c, Timestamp = 237057153 }
[2018-03-08 14:15:50Z INFO HttpTrace] Trace System.Net.Http.Response event:
{ Response = StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 14:15:32 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 324
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
}, LoggingRequestId = ab31853f-a392-486f-b288-f9ca4bdee28c, TimeStamp = 237507550 }
[2018-03-08 14:15:51Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://siemplify.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection. The connection was closed before all data could be read. Expected 324 bytes, read 0 bytes.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could first upgrade your private build agent by right-click the agent pool, and then click **Update all agents**. The latest version of build agent is  2.129.1.

After updating the agent, try to follow the steps in the following link to run a v2 private agent behind a web proxy: [VSTS, TFS 2018 RTM and newer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/proxy?tabs=windows#vsts-tfs-2018-rtm-and-newer):

Pass `--proxyurl`, `--proxyusername` and `--proxypassword` during agent configuration.

For example:

```
./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername "1" --proxypassword "1"
```

Comment: I've tried this method as well. But still I couldn't register the agent. When looking at the logs I get this status code 400:

{ Response = StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Date: Sun, 11 Mar 2018 08:12:50 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 324
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
}

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the proxy file that you created doesn't have spaces around the proxy address which you mention in the proxy file. Make sure you trim it off.

More info here [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/165)